# React. Debouncing function that implements setState method

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components, debouncing

i am developing a simple hoc component that passes viewport dimensions to its children. On window resize, I initiate handleResize method to pass new window dimensions into child component. I want to use debounce func from lodash to minimize number of times that handleResize method is called([ref](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/)).

```
import React from 'react'

import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'

const getDimensions = (Component) => {
  return class GetDimensions extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
      super()

      this.state = {
        viewport: {
          x: window.innerWidth,
          y: window.innerHeight
        }
      }
    }

    handleResize = () => {
      this.setState(() => ({viewport: {x: window.innerWidth, y: window.innerHeight}}))
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
      if (window) window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(this.handleResize, 400))
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
      if (window) window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
    }

    render () {
      return (
        <Component
          {...this.props}
          viewport={this.state.viewport}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}

export default getDimensions
```

It works as expected but i keep getting the warning that:
[image]

does anyone knows what is going on?

please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep in mind you are not removing the event. `if (window) window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(this.handleResize, 400))` will mutate the function and return a wrapped function, the removal of the event just passes the original `this.handleResize`, which won't be found.

you need to `this.handleResize = debounce(this.handleResize, 400)` in the constructor.

tl;dr: component will unmount but event will continue firing.

Comment: Dimitar Christoff, thanks for the the answer and explanation! works!